# Running containers one-time or periodic in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

How to deploy and run a container in Kubernetes, that should do his job and terminate?

I thought this is what [Run-Once](https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.2/admin_guide/limit_runonce_pod_duration.html) is for, but it looks like [it's not supported to work](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24725).

I have some jobs, packed in docker images, that should be run either once/on demand (data import), where the config change should trigger re-run, or periodically (like volume backup). My idea was to deploy a container with `restartPolicy: never` which would stop and scale up to null after accomplishing.

What alternatives do I have for this missing functionality?

Comment: What exact functionality is missing? Isn't https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/ what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you waht a task to be executed just once, or just when you want, you should define a job.
From the oficial documentation you can see this example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

If you want to execute a task periodically, you should define a job and also a cronjob, defining the frequence you want the job to be executed. The following example is also from the oficial documentation:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a job/cronjob. This example is from kubernetes docs:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi
spec:
  backoffLimit: 5
  activeDeadlineSeconds: 100
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

So, it will calculate "pi" and will terminate